# Tooltip for line segments instead of points in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to represent histograms with bins of unequal width with line segments and I can't figure out a way to display one tooltip per line segment instead of the end points.

I'm also using vertical line segments for error bars, and ideally would like a horizontal and a vertical bar to behave as a single marker. Is that possible? I want to be able to draw multiple histograms represented in this way on one chart.

Here's my setup in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znu1Lzht/15/

```
function h1(name,bins,vals,errs) {
  series = [ ];
  var nbins = bins.length - 1;
  var errs_ok = Array.isArray(errs) && (errs.length == nbins);
  for (var i=0; i<nbins; ++i) {
    var bin = { 'type': 'line', 'name': name,
      'data': [[bins[i],vals[i]],[bins[i+1],vals[i]]]
    };
    bin[i==0 ? 'id' : 'linkedTo'] = name;
    series.push(bin);
    if (!errs_ok) continue;
    var x = (bins[i]+bins[i+1])/2;
    var y = [vals[i]-errs[i],vals[i]+errs[i]];
    var err = { 'type': 'line', 'name': name, 'linkedTo': name,
      'data': [[x,y[0]],[x,y[1]]]
    };
    series.push(err);

  }
  return series;
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        color: '#000099',
        lineWidth: 2,
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
          states: { hover: { enabled: false } }
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: { shared: true, crosshairs: true },
    series: h1('test',[0,1,5,10,20],[100,50,30,7],[5,5,5,8])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the tooltip for specific series by setting `tooltip.pointFormat` to `false`:

```
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: false
  }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7qxz5Ldv/